# Integrate Apache Shiro with RestEasy

Tags: resteasy, shiro

I have a REST provider implemented using RestEasy. Currently the API uses method level security but we prefer URL-based security of Shiro. Our application uses CDI for dependency injection and it would be really great if currently logged in users can be injected into the beans since that would allow us to alter our responses based on user roles.

Are there any tutorials or examples that show how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the [SecurityContext](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html) to obtain the UserPrincipal:

```java
@Context
private SecurityContext securityContext;
...
Principal principal = securityContext.getUserPrincipal();
```

If you need more information about the user you can use a CDI producer which fetches the User from e.g. a database:

```java
public class UserProducer {

    @Inject 
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Produces
    public User getUser() {
        Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
        User user = db.fetchUser(principal.getName());
        return user;
    }

}
```

Then inject the User like this:

```java
@Inject
private User user;
```

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I answered the question how the currently logged in users can be injected.